# Vi colour scheme issue

Tags: vi

Im unable to display any colour schemes. They either show nothing or all one colour (??)

```
[root@monty ~]# ls -l .vim/colors/
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9432 Nov 13  2009 bjornenki-colorscheme.vim
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1459 Jan 22  2007 wombat.vim

[root@monty ~]# cat .vimrc
colorscheme bjornenki-colorscheme
syntax on
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: syntax highlighting also depends on the file that you're viewing... what kind of file is it? is the language being correctly identified by vim?

Comment: what is the best way to tell, the html file is fully tagged.

Comment: The answers to my question are thus "html" and "I guess it doesn't matter now" ;)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was I was using vi instead of vim.